# Create a java loop that calculates the age of the user when he/she inputs a birth year, any ideas?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, do-while, jcreator

I am complying a project in computer programming and is new to programming, our professor wants us to 'write a program with loop that will calculate the year of the user and outputs his/her age'.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class lisuuh {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int myyear, result;


    do{
        System.out.print("Enter your birth year: ");
        myyear = sc.nextInt();

        result = myyear - year;
    }while(result == result);
    System.out.print("You are "+result+"year/s old.");


    }
}
```

Expected output:

Enter a Year: 2010

You are 9 Year/s old.

Comment: `}while(result == result);` unless there are more than one threads modifying value of `result` your condition is basically `}while(true);` which means control flow will not leave this loop and will never print result, so maybe move printing *inside* the loop and explicitly write `while(true)` to avoid confusion.

Comment: I didn't know man .. sorry , I'll try it now

Comment: OR "loop that will calculate the year" probably should't be used to ask for many dates of birth, but to loop over years until it will find *current* year and stop. Number of iterations may be used to reflect age.

Comment: can this be done using for looping ?

Comment: if yes , please provide me an example

Comment: It can but why? `while` loop would be easier here, something like `int age = 0; while(userYear < current year){ userYear++; age++;}`. But that is still just a guess since I don't know what was the intention of author of this task.

Comment: I just thought that iteration can be done by the use of for loop

Comment: can you please sent me a chat ?

Comment: I got a couple of questions

Comment: thanks you saved the day !!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer should change like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class lisuuh {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int myyear, result;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter your birth year: ");
            myyear = sc.nextInt();
            result = myyear - year;
        } while(result>0); // this line changed
            System.out.println("You are "+result+"year/s old.");//line changed


    }
}
```